# Datetime entries turns into code

Tags: sql-server-2012

Hi I was generating a script so that my mssql datas would be in a sql format. After that I have a datetime column. An example entry is **2015-02-15 09:45:39.000**
It turned into **CAST(0x0000A44000A0DA84 AS DateTime)**
How would I turn it into **2015-02-15 09:45:39** *Removing the .000 and retaining the yyyy-mm-dd format*?

Comment: What code did you use to do the transformation?

Comment: On the database I right clicked Tasks->Generate Script

Comment: It sounds like you _generated_ code which makes the `CAST`.  Then why are you surprised by the output?

Comment: I was hoping It would produce **2015-02-15 09:45:39.000** in the query. Because I'm planning to migrate to mysql for a certain project

Comment: If you run the script, it should do this.

Comment: In what way could I produce the script for my table without getting that result?

Answer (score 0):

You only want to remove the milliseconds?

- convert it:

  ```
  Select convert(varchar(50), getdate(), 120)
  ```

  output = `2015-08-17 12:01:26`
- or set ms to 000:

  ```
  Select DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, getdate()), getdate())
  ```

  output = `2015-08-17 12:01:26.000`